# Android Spinner - prevent close after refresh

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a dropdown spinner that shows a list of items, and this list updates every X seconds after receiving a response from the API.

The problem is that when the list updates, the spinner automatically closes. I want it to remain opened after the refresh.

```
private void getItems(JSONArray j){
   ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i=0; i < j.length(); i++){
       try {
           //Getting json object
           JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

           //Adding the name of the student to array list
           items.add(json.getString("name"));
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(BaseActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items));
}
```

Comment: can you provide your json array string?

Comment: You are reseting the adapter. I do not think you can keep the dropdown open

Comment: Just Add spinner.performClick(); line below setting adapter in above code, if it throws error then you need to write the same line inside main thread

Comment: Actually, you just need to initialize and add the adapter to the spinner first. Then you load your data, add the data to the adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I made a test similar to K Neeraj Lal's answer and it is works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a demo that shows how you can update the `Spinner` while keeping it open.

First initialize the `Spinner` by setting the `adapter` using `setAdapter`.

Then an update comes for the items. I used a `Handler` to mimic the update. Inside the `getItems` method instead of creating a new adapter (as you have done) use `notifyDataSetChanged` to notify the adapter that the dataset has changed.

Code below.

```
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    initializeSpinner();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String updatedItems = "[{\"name\" : \"test1\"}, {\"name\" : \"test2\"}, {\"name\" : \"test2\"}]";
                getItems(new JSONArray(updatedItems));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 10000);

}


private void initializeSpinner() {
    items.add("initial");

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TestActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getItems(JSONArray j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            items.add(json.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: So I tested your code and it works for me, however I noticed I still had this issue when I used it in the app I'm making. I narrowed it down to one line of code that causes the issue: `testText.setText("some string: " + variable);` where testText is just a textView on the same page.

Question is why does updating a textview in a runnable close a spinner?

Comment: @FergusThePlant I can't comment without seeing the code. Please post it as a different question and post its link here,

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just need to initialize and add the adapter to the spinner first. Then you load your data, add the data to the adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Here is my test activity, you can copy paste it directly to your activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(linearLayout);

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new ArrayList<String>());
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("load data");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TestActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHandler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadData();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });

    linearLayout.addView(spinner);
    linearLayout.addView(button);
}

private void loadData() {
    String jsonArray = "[\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"dada1\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"dada2\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"dada3\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"id\": \"4\",\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"dada4\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \n" +
            "]";
    try {
        getItems(new JSONArray(jsonArray));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

private void getItems(JSONArray j) {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            items.add(json.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    adapter.addAll(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How to test it?

- Run the activity
- Press the button
- After 2 seconds your items is generated
- Press the button again and press the spinner immediately
- You will see that the items is added without closing the popup after 2 seconds